# Is it possible to schedule queries in Google BigQuery using standard SQL such that date range increments everyday while it runs?

Tags: sql, firebase, google-analytics, google-bigquery, scheduled-tasks

I'm firing a query which contains a clause `WHERE (_TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN "20190916" AND "20190917")`, I want to schedule a query such that it triggers daily with the date range incremented by one. Is it possible to do so using standard SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the @run_date variable in scheduled queries.

```sql
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", DATE_SUB(@run_date, INTERVAL 1 Day))
```